# OVRDBF command doesn't work in a CLLE module which contains a submit job

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have CLLE program, which is both module and program. I have a OVRDBF command in the Program and it is a Submit job. But the OVRDBF command is failing.  Earlier it was a only a program and not a module and was working fine. when I change to module, the command is failing. Why doesnt it work. Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: By failing, do you mean the command is generating an error or the OVRDBF isn't taking effect?

Comment: you aren't expecting the OVRDBF to be effective in the submitted job are you?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response. I found the reason for failure of OVRDBF command when it is changed from Program to module. By Default OVRDBF command takes the OPNSCOPE as *ACTGRPDFN. As the CLLE program was compiled with Create program, the Actgrp was changed and the OVRDBF was failing. I have given OPNSCOPE for OVRDBF command as *JOB. Now the Problem is solved :)